# Super root function

Tags: tetration

[Super root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Super-root) is an invertion of [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). Lets define $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}_s$. Definition makes sense when x is integer. Is there an extension of this function to real numbers? Similar how Gamma function extends factorial.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, though extensions of tetrations have been proposed, there isn't one that's conventionally, widely accepted. Thus I suppose that extensions of the super roots exist, but that none is conventionally defined.

Comment: If something useful should exist, it's rather the (analoguous)  pentation-"squareroot". Unfortunately the pentation is not remotely so far developed as the tetration. Maybe you find something in the "tetration-forum"   http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum

Comment: What do you want to know that you can't find on Wikipedia?